# Log level in Jboss as 7 classloaders

Tags: classloader, jboss7.x

How do I change the log level for the classloaders in Jboss as 7?

As a side note;
I have found information on how to do this in Jboss 5 and below but since the classloading and logging has completely changed in Jboss 7 I cant figure out how to do it.

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EnableClassloaderLogging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to JAVA_OPTS in your start up script.

```
-verbose:class
```

And the following to your Jboss config file (standalone.xml for example).

```
<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.deployment">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
    </subsystem>
</profile>
```